# Second screen does not work on "Join Displays"

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I'm using a LG TV as a second screen but it does not work when the "Join Display" option is selected.  It works correctly when "Mirror" is selected. I have no idea about drivers and I'm new to Linux. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3.
It is a HP laptop with rizen 5 and its integrated gpu (i don't know what is it exactly), they are connected by hdmi

Comment: What hardware do you have? Is this a laptop or desktop computer? What model GPU does your computer have?  How exactly are all of the displays connected to your computer?

Comment: Please run `xrandr -q` in a terminal window and edit your question with the results of that command.

Comment: Excuse me, i forgot to tell it, now it's updated

Comment: What do you mean "they" are connected by HDMI? How many displays do you have in total, including the built in display? If you do not know the model CPU, then look it up! Also provide the requested output from the other comment. Please be thorough in your edits and responses so that we don't have to ask repeatedly for information that may be essential to fix your problem